# Magento2 - How to display mini cart scroll?

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I want to display minicart scrollbar when there is more then 4 product in cart i tried to set it from

> Store-> Configuration -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart

Sidebar but it not work for me
[image: 2]

Answer (score 2):

You can use this css to display minicart scroll

```
.minicart-items-wrapper  {
      max-height: 400px !important;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you use custom theme in your magento instance may be they have changed something in sidebar.js file, try below file to debug more for scrollbar not coming in minicart.

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Checkout/web/js/sidebar.js
```